# Function not returning results

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refactor some complexity into a function called getData but code that calls this function doesn't seem to be getting the results.

```
function getData(sql) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) return;
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
      if (err) return;
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        console.log(rows);    // This outputs result from table
        return rows;
      } else {
        return [{"error":"Not found"}];
      }
    });
    connection.end();
  });
}
```

However, when it is called from a function like this, I get undefined returned, even though code inside the function works fine.

```
app.get('/1/employees/past', function(req, res, next) {
    var rows = getData("select * from users");
    res.json(rows);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `return` is returning from the inner function, which doesn't affect the outer function.

You'd need to capture it and return it, and seeing as it appears to work with callbacks, you'd need to pass an additional callback to `getData()`.

Something like this...

```
function getData(sql, callback) {
     // ...    
     connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
         // ...
         callback && callback(rows); // etc
     });
     // ...
}
```

If you wanted to be *safer*, ensure the callback implements `[[Call]]` with [`typeof`](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-typeof) (link to my own blog post).

Answer (score 0):

The `getData` function is not returning anything! The `getConnection` function *inside* the `getData` function is calling a function which calls a function which returns something; the `getData` function itself is not returning anything.

What's more, if this code executes asynchronously, all the returns will execute long after the `getData` function has returned.

You're either going the synchronous `return` route or the asynchronous callback route, you can't mix both styles.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` function does not return anything - the return statements inside the code are all for the anonymous functions which you pass into `connection.query` and `connection.query`.

Your connection-related function are asynchronous - i.e. they return immediately after you call them without waiting for any results to be available. If you want to do something with the results which get returned you need to do it inside one of the anonymous functions, rather than trying to do it as soon as `getData` completes.